# Music folder missing

Tags: music, data-loss

I was downloading music from linux dc++ to music folder in my PC , after downloading all files i couldn't open music folder as whenever i tried to do so it showed error that NO SUCH DIRECTORY EXISTS ?

Comment: I had the same problem. Please look at folder `"/home/[username]/.dc++/filelist"` Probably DC++ moved it into this folder :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs file (type this in terminal `gedit ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`). Make sure the contents of the file are like the following(or just copy-paste and overwrite with this):

```
XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Desktop"
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Downloads"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Share"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Music"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Videos"
```

Then restart nautilus:

type `nautilus -q` in terminal and hit enter
Then, open nautilus via Unity menu